# Extraer datos de un archivo json para mapa en folium con python

Tags: python, json, mapa, folium

Estoy intentando crear un mapa choropleth usando folium con datos que he encontrado en internet. Si utilizo el archivo *json*, se muestra el mapa correctamente, pero como yo sólo necesito datos para los primeros 6 distritos, el resto de distritos aparecen coloreados en gris oscuro.

Me gustaría extraer los datos de los 6 distritos que necesito para que el mapa se muestre correctamente, pero me sale este error: `Cannot render objects with any missing geometries: [{'coordinates': [[[[-3.705989, 40.420264],.....`

Soy nueva usando python y folium y creo que me estoy saltando algún paso intermedio, pero no he encontrado cómo hacer esto en ninguna parte. Puede que sea porque estoy intentando crear el mapa con una lista de coordenadas en lugar de un archivo *json*. Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
!wget --quiet https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Saigesp/8ca8ca2a4ce33e8e9efe8f5752683f88/raw/81d61ae9a410a59cb512dd7b01ba9bd5c98c8380/fixed_ESP_MAD_adm6.json

import json

communities_geo = r'fixed_ESP_MAD_adm6.json'

with open(communities_geo) as f:
    gj = json.load(f)

neighb_json = []
for index in range(6):
    neighb_json.append(gj['features'][index]['geometry'])

restaurant_map2 = folium.Map(location=[40.416775, -3.703790], zoom_start=15)

restaurant_map2.choropleth(
    geo_data=neighb_json,
    data=df5_count,
    columns=['Neighborhood', 'Venue Category'],
    key_on='feature.properties.geometry',
    fill_color='YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Restaurants')

restaurant_map2
```

Si utilizo `communities_geo` en `geo_data` el mapa funciona, pero no puedo utilizar sólo los primeros datos del archivo json. ¿Podéis ayudarme?

Muchas gracias!!! :D

EDITO: Estos son los datos a cargar llamados `df5_count`:

|  | Neighborhood | Venue Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Cortes | 32 |
| 1 | Embajadores | 21 |
| 2 | Justicia | 32 |
| 3 | Palacio | 20 |
| 4 | Sol | 23 |
| 5 | Universidad | 27 |

Y estos serían los datos del primer distrito del archivo *json* (el archivo está en la URL de la primera línea de código), pero necesitaría utilizar los 6 primeros distritos (el archivo tiene unos 40 distritos):

```json
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"geometry": {"coordinates": [[[[-3.705989, 40.420264], [-3.706397, 40.420149], [-3.708175, 40.420214], [-3.707973, 40.419844], [-3.708059, 40.419606], [-3.708196, 40.419141], [-3.708247, 40.418862], [-3.708509, 40.418376], [-3.708532, 40.418336], [-3.708584, 40.418249], [-3.70884, 40.417804], [-3.708638, 40.417774], [-3.708733, 40.417194], [-3.708762, 40.41709], [-3.708784, 40.416999], [-3.708746, 40.416755], [-3.708744, 40.416737], [-3.708714, 40.416465], [-3.708682, 40.416353], [-3.708755, 40.416269], [-3.708725, 40.415957], [-3.708777, 40.415826], [-3.70887, 40.415558], [-3.708668, 40.415303], [-3.708606, 40.415298], [-3.708541, 40.415295], [-3.708491, 40.415263], [-3.708247, 40.414722], [-3.708091, 40.414499], [-3.708175, 40.414088], [-3.708317, 40.413694], [-3.707784, 40.413554], [-3.707537, 40.413496], [-3.707487, 40.413315], [-3.707632, 40.412563], [-3.707775, 40.412448], [-3.708293, 40.411336], [-3.708487, 40.411235], [-3.708542, 40.411144], [-3.709208, 40.410353], [-3.710162, 40.40914], [-3.710287, 40.408994], [-3.711104, 40.407978], [-3.711737, 40.406641], [-3.712107, 40.406721], [-3.713752, 40.40742], [-3.71529, 40.408059], [-3.716829, 40.408674], [-3.718397, 40.411089], [-3.71791, 40.412054], [-3.716998, 40.413892], [-3.718598, 40.41389], [-3.719491, 40.413911], [-3.719696, 40.413916], [-3.720554, 40.413929], [-3.723012, 40.413966], [-3.722909, 40.415308], [-3.722438, 40.417151], [-3.722219, 40.418012], [-3.722112, 40.418436], [-3.721901, 40.418557], [-3.721568, 40.418747], [-3.721125, 40.419095], [-3.720758, 40.419446], [-3.720458, 40.419871], [-3.720357, 40.420045], [-3.720254, 40.420221], [-3.720248, 40.420231], [-3.718119, 40.420301], [-3.716861, 40.420318], [-3.716038, 40.42033], [-3.715563, 40.420379], [-3.715563, 40.420379], [-3.713955, 40.421454], [-3.71344, 40.421798], [-3.71339, 40.421881], [-3.713233, 40.422035], [-3.713102, 40.422164], [-3.711781, 40.42294], [-3.711221, 40.423268], [-3.710976, 40.423398], [-3.710953, 40.42341], [-3.710228, 40.422925], [-3.707988, 40.421519], [-3.705989, 40.420264]]]], "type": "MultiPolygon"}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"created_at": "2013-12-02T07:16:22+0100", "cartodb_id": 1, "name": "Palacio", "updated_at": "2013-12-02T07:16:22+0100"}}]}
```

EDITO2:

Este código que utiliza el json original de la url sí que me funciona, pero como digo, me sale el resto de distritos en gris y por eso estoy intentando eliminarlos:

```
!wget --quiet https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Saigesp/8ca8ca2a4ce33e8e9efe8f5752683f88/raw/81d61ae9a410a59cb512dd7b01ba9bd5c98c8380/fixed_ESP_MAD_adm6.json

import folium

communities_geo = r'fixed_ESP_MAD_adm6.json' # geojson file

restaurant_map = folium.Map(location=[40.416775, -3.703790], zoom_start=15)

restaurant_map.choropleth(
    geo_data=communities_geo,
    data=df5_count,
    columns=['Neighborhood', 'Venue Category'],
    key_on='feature.properties.name',
    fill_color='YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Restaurants'
)

restaurant_map
```

Muchas gracias!! :D

Comment: Incluye un ejemplo del contenido del archivo que cargas.

Comment: He editado con los datos que uso para colorear el mapa y las coordenadas que se utilizan para bordear el primer distrito del mapa. Si necesitas algún dato más avísame. Mil gracias!!! :D

Comment: El _json_ que publicas está incompleto. Quizás, para comenzar, de allí venga el problema. También veo que el segundo _json_ que derivas del primero no tiene la misma estructura. Lo dejo solo como comentario, ya que no tengo manera de hacer una prueba rápida con lo que has publicado. Considera publicar un [mcve], quizás eso ayude a que alguien te eche un cable. Un saludo.

Comment: Mil gracias por responder @jachguate !! He editado de nuevo el post original, espero estar haciéndolo bien ya que es mi primera vez escribiendo aquí. El código que acabo de poner sí que funciona e imprime el mapa, pero no queda bonito al ser en gris algunas partes.

Comment: He editado el código parcial del json en el post también, ya que al copiar sólo los datos del primer distrito, no había cerrado las llaves como corresponde, ahora ese ejemplo debería ser correcto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comenzaré diciendo que no conozco folium, pero si puedo ver que estás produciendo una estructura muy diferente a la que trae el archivo de entrada y los programas suelen ser poco flexibles con respecto de las estructuras que aceptan de entrada, que suelen estar bien documentadas justamente por lo mismo.

Dicho esto, no es tan complicado reproducir una estructura igual, pero debes dedicar cierto tiempo, primero, a observar/entender que es lo que trae el archivo original, y a leer la documentación al respecto.

Yo no he hecho más que parte la primera tarea de estas y he hecho una rutina que reproduce la misma estructura, con menos datos que, supongo, resolverá tu problema. Si no lo hace, considero que te corresponde a ti informarte y encontrar qué le falta o qué le sobra para ser aceptada como parámetro por el componente.

El archivo trae un único objeto con el atributo `"type": FeatureCollection`. Este objeto tiene además un atributo `"features"` que es un arreglo de objetos que tienen una serie de atributos, que ya no hace falta conocer, pues supongo que son los primeros seis objetos de este arreglo íntegros los que quieres pasar.

He descargado el *json* que has referenciado, lo tengo guardado en disco duro local y al final, el resultado lo guardo en un nuevo `json` en la misma carpeta.

```
import json

allFeaturesFileName = r'c:\test\json\folium.json'
firstFeaturesFileName = r'c:\test\json\somefolium.json'

with open(allFeaturesFileName) as f:
    allFeatures = json.load(f)

firstFeatures = {}
firstFeatures['type'] = "FeatureCollection"
firstFeatures['features'] = []


for index in range(6):
    firstFeatures['features'].append(allFeatures['features'][index])

with open(firstFeaturesFileName, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(firstFeatures, outfile)
```

Finalizo insistiendo en la importancia de mantener la estructura. He verificado el resultado que produce mi código y creo que se está logrando a nivel de *json*, pero tampoco tengo forma de comprobarlo con el uso final en folium.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la explicación!! Tú código funciona perfectamente y el mapa ya se muestra como yo quería! He analizado la diferencia de tu código y el que estaba intentando yo y ahora ya comprendo el fallo que estaba teniendo. Siendo nueva todavía tengo mucho que aprender pero intento poco a poco entender todas las cosas para la próxima vez ser capaz de hacerlo yo. Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ayudar a una novata! Gracias mil!!! :D

Comment: Un placer ser de ayuda, si sigues con esa actitud vas a ir por buen camino. :)